# PlaceAutocomplete Location Faliure

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am implementing an app where I have implemented a map in and over the map there is a textview which shows address where the marker is placed. If the map is dragged the address changes in the textview. Now as soon as I touch the textview PlaceAutoFragment is implemented.

```
 relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                getSearchLocation();
                return true;
            }
        });

    private void getSearchLocation(){
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Enter Location");
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
        }
        try {
            Intent intent =
                    new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                            .build(getActivity());
            startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        }
    }
```

As soon as I select any location based on the text I type in the this fragment. I get response here

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(getActivity(), data);
                if(sourceMarker != null) sourceMarker.remove();
                setCurrentLocationMarker(place.getLatLng());
                Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());
            } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
                Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(getActivity(), data);
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.i(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // The user canceled the operation.
            }
        }
    }
```

Look and feel of the design is good.
**Now the problem here is.**
 1. It doesnot respond in a single go when ever I choose any option from list of location.
 2. Even If it shows response the location it points doesnot corresponds with the name.

Comment: Was there a reason you did not want to use marker popups to show the address?  This would play much more friendly with the maps API.

Comment: I am trying to copy UBER app.